# How to decode Seagate's hard drive date code in a Bash script

Tags: bash

[Seagate](http://www.seagate.com) hard drives display a code instead of the manufacturing date. The code is described [here](http://www.lerti.fr/web/public/NoteTechnique03-v1.01.pdf) and an online decoder is available [here](http://www.westernnetworks.com/tools/seagatedatecode2.php).

In short, it's a 4 or 5 digit number of the form `YYWWD` or `YYWD`, where:

- `YY` is the year, 00 is year 1999
- `W` or `WW` is the week number beginning 1
- `D` is day of week beginning 1
- Week 1 begins on the first saturday of July in the stated year

Examples

- 06212 means Sunday 20 November 2005
- 0051  means Saturday 31 July 1999

How can this be decoded in a `bash` script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did, it should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$1
REGEX="^(..)(..?)(.)$"

[[ $DATE =~ $REGEX ]]
YEAR=$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} + 1999 ))
WEEK=$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - 1))
DAYOFWEEK=$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} - 1))


OFFSET=$(( 6 - $(date -d "$YEAR-07-01" +%u) ))
DATEOFFIRSTSATURDAY=$(date -d "$YEAR-7-01 $OFFSET days" +%d)
FINALDATE=`date -d  "$YEAR-07-$DATEOFFIRSTSATURDAY $WEEK weeks $DAYOFWEEK days"`

echo $FINALDATE
```

It worked for the two dates given above...
If you want to customize the date output, add a format string at the end of the FINALDATe assignment.

Comment: I like the way you got the starting date using `%u`; it's cleaner than what I tried.

Comment: Yeah, I tried parsing the output of `cal` as well... It is really unstable!

Comment: I did not mean to EDIT the original post, only to suggest a fix.

Comment: The year YY and week WW can have a leading 0 which tells bash a number is octal (base 8).  
But 08 and 09 are invalid octal numbers.

Add `10#` to force interpretation to decimal (base 10).

    YEAR=$(( 10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]} + 1999 ))
    WEEK=$(( 10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - 1 ))

Comment: Both links don't exist anymore, but the decode sounds correct...

Comment: Found another online converter: https://bugaco.com/calculators/seagate_date_code.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short script, it takes two arguments: `$1` is the code to convert and `$2` is an optional format (see `man date`), otherwise defaulted (see code).

It uses the last Saturday in June instead of the first one in July because I found it easer to locate and it allowed me to just add the relevant number of weeks and days to it.

```
#!/bin/bash
date_format=${2:-%A %B %-d %Y}

code=$1
[[ ${#code} =~ ^[4-5]$ ]] || { echo "bad code"; exit 1; }

let year=1999+${code:0:2}
[[ ${#code} == 4 ]] && week=${code:2:1} || week=${code:2:2}
day=${code: -1}

june_last_saturday=$(cal 06 ${year} | awk '{ $6 && X=$6 } END { print X }')

date -d "${year}-06-${june_last_saturday} + ${week} weeks + $((${day}-1)) days" "+${date_format}"
```

Examples:

```
$ seadate 06212
Sunday November 20 2005
$ seadate 0051
Saturday July 31 1999
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a Seagate Date Code Calculator that actually works with pretty good accuracy.  I've posted it here on this forum for anyone to use:  https://www.data-medics.com/forum/seagate-date-code-conversion-translation-tool-t1035.html#p3261

It's far more accurate than the other ones online which often point to the entirely wrong year.  I know it's not a bash script, but will still get the job done for anyone else who's searching how to do this.

Enjoy!